# How to pass variables/functions from javaScript to Python and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, python, artificial-intelligence, nltk

I am creating a website in HTML, CSS and JavaScript where I require an AI powered chatbot. I have the required python file which consists of the logic for the chatbot (AI, NLTK). Now, in the python file, I have a function named "response()" which takes the user message as an argument and returns the processed response after running the NLP logic.
What I want to do is, As soon as the user sends a message,

1. The JavaScript would store that message in a variable (say, user-response) and should send that variable as an argument to the python file's "response()" function: response(user-response)
2. The Python file should use the response(user-response) function and send the processed output to the JavaScript file

How do I achieve this?

Here's the python logic

```
def response(user_response):     #This argument has to be passed from JavaScript
    robo_response = ''
    sent_tokens.append(user_response)
    TfIdVec = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=LemNormalize, stop_words='english')
    tfidf = TfIdVec.fit_transform(sent_tokens)
    vals = cosine_similarity(tfidf[-1], tfidf)
    idx = vals.argsort()[0][-2]
    flat = vals.flatten()
    flat.sort()
    req_tfidf = flat[-2]

    GREETING_INPUTS = ("hello", "hi", "greetings", "sup", "what's up", "hey")
    GREETING_RESPONSES = ["hi", "hey", "*nods*", "hi there", "hello", "I'm glad you're talking to me"]
    for word in user_response.split():
        if (word.lower() in GREETING_INPUTS):
            return random.choice(GREETING_RESPONSES)


    if(req_tfidf == 0):
        robo_response = [
            "Sorry, I have not been trained to answer that yet!", 
            "Sorry, I cannot answer to that!
            ]
        return random.choice(robo_response);
        
        robo_response = robo_response+sent_tokens[idx]
        return robo_response;

response("")     #This response has to be sent back to JavaScript
```

Here's the JavaScript code

```
function returnsUserMessage(){
    var userResponse = document.getElementById('input-chat').value;
    console.log(userResponse);
    return userResponse;
}
```

Comment: Your client-side code will have to make network requests to your server. Your Python code will have to be integrated into your server so that it can dispatch incoming requests and return responses. Exactly how you do all that is a very large topic for a single Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will put few steps for you to go through but as @Pointy said in the comment, "Exactly how you do all that is a very large topic for a single Stack Overflow question", so consider this as a roadmap.

Side note: I assume you don't want to execute the AI logic in the frontend as this will be heavy on the client.

1- Create a backend server (or REST API) with Python.

2- Inject your AI logic in HTTP requests (GET/POST).

Backend is a big topic but I will provide a small example here:

```py
from flask import Flask, json, request

def response(user_response):
    ...
api = Flask(__name__)

@api.route('/response', methods=['POST'])
def post_response():
  user_response = json.loads(request.json)["user_response"]
  return json.dumps({response: response(user_response)})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    api.run()
```

3- From the frontend, send the user input to the backend (using the HTTP request you created in step 2) and then write back the response.

Example:

```
<button onclick="returnsUserMessage()">Send</button>

<script>
async function returnsUserMessage() {
  var user_input = document.getElementById("input-chat").value;
  var bot_reponse = await fetch('localhost/response',
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({user_response: user_input})
    });
  // Then you need to present the bot response in your element
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please consider providing some source code to support the given answer explaining show how it solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to achieve it using flask. However, Is there a way by which I can achieve the same using ajax?

Comment: @HarshilPatel I think yes but I am not an ajax expert. If you think my answer helped you, please vote up and consider accepting my answer.